# Can't pip install protobuf and mediapipe

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, mediapipe

I'm trying to install mediapipe with pip install mediapipe, but I'm seeing this error:

protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.6

I'm assuming that I have to use a python version after 3.7 and not 3.6.6. However, is there a way to install protobuf regardless? I've done quite some setups on my python 3.6 virtual environments, so I don't want to do all of them again.

Comment: If a package says it requires a certain minimum version of Python, it requires that version. New features get added to the language with each successive release, and libraries take advantage of those features. Their code won't work if you have an earlier version. I suggest upgrading to the latest version, 3.10. 3.11 is just about out, but not all packages support it yet.

Comment: I agree with @MattDMo
You can try with Docker to execute your code into an image, or you can upgrade you local Python version

Comment: If you do not want to upgrade for some reason, you might want to do the following: ```pip install protobuf==3.6.0```